# Using pyarrow dataset for many small parquet files to iteratively insert in batches into deltalake

Tags: dataset, pyarrow

We have a high number of small parquet files in our az blob storage. We want to copy everything into a deltalake. We want to do that efficiently and memory efficient. I tried to use pyarrows dataset to set all parquet files into a dataset and than call `to_batches`. Unfortunately, pyarrow does not scan and merge multiple files to return the desired `batch_size`, it just returns one file as one batch (like it is described in the documentation). However, appending or merging too many small files to the deltalake causes many tiny files and need a high overhead of compacting.

Is there any way to efficiently process through the files and do as few as possible interactions to the deltatable? Is it possible to adjust the fragments, that a dataframe having multiple files at once is returned?

Here is my code:

```py
def read_parquet_files_from_azure(container_name, connection_string, prefix, fs_in):
    # Create a blob service client
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)

    # # Get a container client
    container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)

    # # Get all blob names in the container with the given prefix
    blob_names = [blob.name for blob in container_client.list_blobs(name_starts_with=prefix)]

    # # Create a list of full blob URIs
    blob_uris = [f"{container_name}/{blob_name}" for blob_name in blob_names]

    # Read all parquet files into a single PyArrow dataset
    dataset = ds.dataset(
        blob_uris,
        format="parquet",
        filesystem=fs_in,
    )

    return dataset


dataset = read_parquet_files_from_azure(
    "migration-dev", os.environ["INPUT_AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING"], "table/", input_fs
)

i = 0
for slice in dataset.to_batches():

    log.info(f"Shape of slice: ({slice.num_rows}, {slice.num_columns})")

    df = slice.to_pandas()

    # Extract the date from the "Date" timestamp column
    # dates = df["Date"].dt.date.values
    dates = df["Date"].dt.to_period("M").astype(str).str.replace("-", "_")  # partition by year-month

    # Convert the pandas DataFrame back to a PyArrow Table
    slice = pa.table(slice).append_column("date_id", pa.array(dates))

    # write to deltalkae table w.r.t. deltalake_write_mode
    write_deltalake(
        storage_options=output_sa,
        table_or_uri=delta_table_path,
        data=slice,
        mode="append",
        partition_by=partition_keys,
        engine="rust",
    )
    i = i + 1

    if i % 10 == 0:
        # COMPACT
        log.info("Compacting")
        delta_table = DeltaTable(
            table_uri=f"""abfs://{os.environ["CONTAINER_DELTALAKE"]}/operating_report/""",
            storage_options=output_sa,
        )
        delta_table_optimizer = TableOptimizer(delta_table)
        log.info(delta_table_optimizer.compact())

    if i % 100 == 0:
        # VACCUM
        log.info("Vacuuming")
        delta_table = DeltaTable(
            table_uri=f"""abfs://{os.environ["CONTAINER_DELTALAKE"]}/operating_report/""",
            storage_options=output_sa,
        )
        log.info(delta_table.vacuum(dry_run=False))
```